# How to maintain String constant across java and xml file?

Tags: android

Many components in Android framework requires string constant to be used across both java and xml file. For example to implement a custom account authenticator with custom account type, we will need to use the account type string "my_custom_account_type" in both `account-authenticator` xml file and java code.

authenticator.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <account-authenticator
        ...
        android:accountType="my_custom_account_type"
        ...
        />
```

and add an account in our app by doing something like this:

```
    Account myAccount = new Account("John", "my_custom_account_type");
    AccountManager.get(mContext).addAccountExplicitly(myAccount, null, null);
```

**Question:** How is this usually accomplished? Do people just make mental note to themselves to always remember to update these strings in multiple places? Is there a standard way to maintain these strings?

**Edit:** I have considered using defining the string constant in a string resource and call Context.getString() to retrieve it in java code. However this will require us to have a `Context` object. I am wondering if there is a more general approach to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a string resource and reference that in both xml and code:

```
<resources>
    <string name="custom_account_type">my_custom_account_type</string>
</resources>
```

then:

```
<account-authenticator
    ...
    android:accountType="@string/custom_account_type"
    ...
    />
```

and:

```
Account myAccount = new Account("John", mContext.getString(R.string.custom_account_type));
```

That way you only have to update the string in one place.

Answer (score 0):

define string in Strings.xml file

the you can use that string in xml using `@string/string_name`.
and in Java you can use

```
getString(R.string.string_name);
```

Comment: But then that would require a context to call getString() from.

Comment: if you are in fragment then call getActivity().getString()

Comment: and if you are in adapter or any other class then pass Activity's context in Constructor of that class/adapter.

example
    class MyClass{
    
    public MyClass(Context context){
    //save this context to globel variable.
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can access the string using`getString(R.string.your_string);` which is declared in `<resources>
    <string name="your_string">Required String Value</string>
</resources>`

Answer (score 0):

Goto `res/values/string.xml` file. Here you can define any string constant you want to use throughout your application.

e.g.

```
<string name="Sample">This is sample string.</string>
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
```

Now, you only have to just refer to string whenever you need.

**For XMl file**

```
android:text="@string/Sample"
```

**For JAVA code**

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.Sample);
```

or

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getText(R.string.Sample);
```

And for Array,

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.string.planets_array)
```

You can use either `getString(int)` or `getText(int)` to retrieve a string. `getText(int)` will retain any rich text styling applied to the string.

Refer the Docs : [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I have considered using defining the string constant in a string resource and call `Context.getString()` to retrieve it in java code. However this will require us to have a Context object. I am wondering if there is a more general approach to this problem.

If it's such a hassle to keep a context object around, you could create a class containing a static String variable and initialize that in a custom application class.

Something like this

```
public class StringRegister{
    static String custom_account_type;

    public static void initialize(Context context){
        this.custom_account_type = context.getResources().getString(R.string.custom_account_type);
    }

    public static String get_custom_account_type(){
        if(custom_account_type != null)
            return custom_account_type;
        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomApp extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        StringRegister.initialize(this);
    }
}
```

add the CustomApp to your Manifest

```
<application
    android:name=".CustomApp"
```

and you can access your String variable by calling **StringRegister.get_custom_account_type()**

**Edit:** I should add that while this works, it isn't pretty. It's cleaner to keep a context object around.

Comment: Consider this: I have a content provider and a SyncAdapter. I define string resource `<string name="my_authority">my.authority</string>`. I have in my syncadapter xml file: `android:contentAuthority="@string/my_authority"`. I have `static final String AUTHORITY = MyApp.getContext().getString(R.string.my_authority)` in my content provider class so i can use UriMatcher. `MyApp` is a subclass of `Application` and `MyApp.getContext()` is a static method which will return an instance of `MyApp` which i stored during the `onCreate()` of `MyApp`. I now allow other apps to access my content provider.

Comment: Will this approach which requires a context still work? I am assuming i will get a NullPointerException when other apps try to access my content provider if `MyApp` is not instantiated.

Comment: Let me rephrase your comment to make sure, I understood it correctly. You want to store the appcontext in a static variable? Possible, but can lead to some huge memory leaks. Quite honestly, before going to such lengths, I'd rather pass the context as a parameter. Your code might need some redesign, if passing the context is an issue.

Edit: I'm also not sure, what you mean with "other apps". The applicationcontext is only accessible by the application itself. App A cannot access the context of App B

Comment: I wanted to maintain string constant in java code and xml. Your answer and many other answers here are variations of keeping the string in resource file and using Context to retrieve the string in java code. My comment which describes an outsider app accessing my content provider is an attempt to find a scenario where it might not be possible (not too sure of this) to have a correct `Context` instance to call `getString()` from.

Comment: Oooh, okay, so what you essentially want is access the same String from different apps. I don't think that's possible from Android Studio (I might be wrong), but you could extract the string resource into a seperate file, keep the same file around in every project that needs it and build a script on your workstation that syncs those files across all projects

Comment: Just to clarify, that isn't what i wanted. There is no different app to access the same String from. I only care about a single app and ensuring that it does not break when it is used in a correct way.